# Form Validation doesn't happen and form submits

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

This is my javascript for my log in page that I'm working on.
So for some reason my form doesn't validate before it sends the form, and also it broke my background rotate plugin.
Hopefully someone out there will be able to help me solve this problem, sorry if this text is so long, I  can't seem to submit this post properly since it keeps asking me to add more detail, but I don't really know what else to add in.

```
var Login = function () {

    return {
        //main function to initiate the module
        init: function () {

            $.backstretch([
                "assets/img/bg/1.jpg",
                "assets/img/bg/2.jpg",
                "assets/img/bg/3.jpg",
                "assets/img/bg/4.jpg"
                ], {
                  fade: 1000,
                  duration: 8000
              });

            $('.login-form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            }).validate({
                errorElement: 'label', //default input error message container
                errorClass: 'help-inline', // default input error message class
                focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
                rules: {
                    username: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    remember: {
                        required: false
                    }
                },

                messages: {
                    username: {
                        required: "Username is required."
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: "Password is required."
                    }
                },

                invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit   
                    $('.alert-error', $('.login-form')).show();
                },

                highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
                    $(element)
                        .closest('.control-group').addClass('error'); // set error class to the control group
                },

                success: function (label) {
                    label.closest('.control-group').removeClass('error');
                    label.remove();
                },

                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    error.addClass('help-small no-left-padding').insertAfter(element.closest('.input-icon'));
                },

                submitHandler: function (form) {
                    $.ajax({
                    url: "loginqry.php",
                    type: "post"
                    data: serializedData
                    {
                    alert(data); // show response from the php script.
                    }
                    })；
                    return false;
                }
            });

            $('.login-form input').keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    $.ajax({
                    url: "loginqry.php",
                    type: "post"
                    data: serializedData
                    {
                    alert(data); // show response from the php script.
                    }
                    })；
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

    };

}();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot chain the [`.validate()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) onto an event handler...

```
$('.login-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}).validate({...});
```

Furthermore, there is no reason to declare a `.submit()` handler in the first place.  The plugin automatically handles the submit event of the form that you bind it to.

Simply do this instead...

```
$('.login-form').validate({...});
```